# Hide the previous table and show new table on click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with which you can select a type. Based on this type I am displaying data in the table.

Now what I want is when I select the first type and click on the submit button that the data displays in the table fine.

When I select the second one and click on the submit button, the data is displaying but previous data are also showing there. How can I remove previous table before creating the new one?

Please help me thanks in Advance.

Here is my html:

```js
$("#reportbtn").on("click", function() {
  jc.open();
  $("#reports_list_cont2").show();
  var transaction_type, report_type;
  transaction_type = $("#transaction_type").val();
  report_type = $('#report_type').val();
  var Table = $("#reports_list_cont2 #cancelled_bill_" + transaction_type).DataTable({
    data: [],
    columns: [{
        "data": "ebillno"
      },
      {
        "data": "ebilldate"
      },
      {
        "data": "Transactiontype"
      },
      {
        "data": "doctype"
      },
      {
        "data": "docno"
      },
      {
        "data": "docdate"
      },
      {
        "data": "billfromgstin"
      },
      {
        "data": "billfromcompany"
      },
      {
        "data": "billtogstin"
      },
      {
        "data": "billtocompany"
      },
      {
        "data": "transpoter_id"
      },
      {
        "data": "transpoter_name"
      },
      {
        "data": "despatchfromaddress"
      },
      {
        "data": "shiptoaddress"
      },
      {
        "data": "quantity"
      },
      {
        "data": "hsncode"
      },
      {
        "data": "taxinvoicevalue"
      },
      {
        "data": "validupto"
      },
      {
        "data": "status"
      }
    ],
    rowCallback: function(row, data) {},
    Filter: false,
    Sort: false,
    JQueryUI: false,
    AutoWidth: false,
    LengthChange: false,
    Processing: true,
    ServerSide: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    searching: false
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: url + 'ajax/get_cancelled_invoice_details',
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'transaction_type': transaction_type,
      'report_type': report_type
    }
  }).done(function(result) {
    Table.clear().draw();
    Table.rows.add(result).draw();
    jc.close();
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // needs to implement if it fails
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-head">Generate Reports</div>
<form name="eway_reports_form" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select name="transaction_type" id="transaction_type" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
        <option value="eway_inward">Inward</option>
        <option value="eway_outward">Outward</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select name="report_type" id="report_type" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Report Type</option>
        <option value="cancelled_eway">Cancelled E-Way </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button id="reportbtn" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="table" id="reports_list_cont2" style="display:none;overflow:auto;">
  <table id="cancelled_bill_eway_outward" class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EwaybillNo</th>
        <th>EBill Date</th>
        <th>Transaction Type</th>
        <th>Document type</th>
        <th>Document No</th>
        <th>Document date</th>
        <th>Bill from GSTIN</th>
        <th>Bill from Companyname</th>
        <th>Bill to GSTIN.</th>
        <th>Bill to company name</th>
        <th>TransporterId</th>
        <th>TransporterName</th>
        <th>Dispatch From Address</th>
        <th>Ship To Address </th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>HSN Code</th>
        <th>Total Invoice Value</th>
        <th>Valid Till Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="cancelled_bill_eway_inward" class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: could you try table.destroy(); before creating a fresh one.

Comment: yes i need to check if first type table is dispalying and hide table and show the second table

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you initialize DataTable on already initialized element.

You can simply destroy it just before reinitializing like this:
Define global variable which you will save as initialized DataTable. Than inside `click` event instead of creating new variable just use this global variable.

And inside the `click` event check if your variable is an DataTable. If it is destroy it.

```
if (table instanceof $.fn.dataTable.Api) {
  table.destroy();
}
```

```js
var table;
$("#reportbtn").on("click", function() {
  if (table instanceof $.fn.dataTable.Api) {
    table.destroy();
  }
  $("#reports_list_cont2").show();
  var transaction_type, report_type;
  transaction_type = $("#transaction_type").val();
  report_type = $('#report_type').val();
  table = $("#reports_list_cont2 #cancelled_bill_" + transaction_type).DataTable({
    data: [],
    columns: [{"data": "ebillno"},{"data": "ebilldate"},{"data": "Transactiontype"},{"data": "doctype"},{"data": "docno"},{"data": "docdate"},{"data": "billfromgstin"},{"data": "billfromcompany"},{"data": "billtogstin"},{"data": "billtocompany"},{"data": "transpoter_id"},{"data": "transpoter_name"},{"data": "despatchfromaddress"},{"data": "shiptoaddress"},{"data": "quantity"},{"data": "hsncode"},{"data": "taxinvoicevalue"},{"data": "validupto"},{"data": "status"}],
    rowCallback: function(row, data) {},
    Filter: false,
    Sort: false,
    JQueryUI: false,
    AutoWidth: false,
    LengthChange: false,
    Processing: true,
    ServerSide: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    searching: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="page-head">Generate Reports</div>
<form name="eway_reports_form" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select name="transaction_type" id="transaction_type" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
        <option value="eway_inward">Inward</option>
        <option value="eway_outward">Outward</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select name="report_type" id="report_type" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Report Type</option>
        <option value="cancelled_eway">Cancelled E-Way </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button id="reportbtn" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="table" id="reports_list_cont2" style="display:none;overflow:auto;">
  <table id="cancelled_bill_eway_outward" class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EwaybillNo</th>
        <th>EBill Date</th>
        <th>Transaction Type</th>
        <th>Document type</th>
        <th>Document No</th>
        <th>Document date</th>
        <th>Bill from GSTIN</th>
        <th>Bill from Companyname</th>
        <th>Bill to GSTIN.</th>
        <th>Bill to company name</th>
        <th>TransporterId</th>
        <th>TransporterName</th>
        <th>Dispatch From Address</th>
        <th>Ship To Address </th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>HSN Code</th>
        <th>Total Invoice Value</th>
        <th>Valid Till Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="cancelled_bill_eway_inward" class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```